# Why does Java regular expression (?i)[A-Z] work for mixed-case but (?i)[\p{Upper}] not?

Tags: java, regex, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm wondering why the regular expression `(?i)[A-Z]` instantiated with Java's class `java.util.regex.Pattern` matches mixed-case characters but `(?i)[\p{Upper}]` doesn't. In my real-world use case I want to prepend the regular expression string `(?i)` to `[\p{Upper}]` at runtime whenever I need to match characters case-insensitively. Switching on case-insensitive matching programmatically, i.e. via the flag `CASE_INSENSITIVE` is not an option.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and if not so what an equivalent approach would look like?

Comment: What about `(?iu)` btw? It's said in the doc that... "case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in conjunction with this flag".

Comment: If you use `\p{Upper}` it just ignores the case insensitive flag. That is it. Even if you use `Pattern.compile("[\\p{Upper}]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`, it won't match lowercase letters. `\p{Upper}` and `[A-Z]` are not equivalent in what they can match, and they are just not equal. Use `\p{L}` to match any letter and `\p{Alpha}` to only match ASCII letters (however, with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, `\p{Alpha}` will also match all Unicode letters).